# Server 2012 smb share without login, and share edit permissions

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, server-message-block, share

So i just installed server 2012 on a proliant microserver.
So far i've managed to set everything up, this server isn't running any advanced setup. Hell i would probably be fine just running win8 on it.

But nevertheless, i don't have a lot of experience with windows server, so this is a decent opportunity for that.

My problem is smb shares. I can create a share. But i would constantly be asked to login to the share. By adding anon, guest and everyone with full permissions i've gotten around the login part. Or so i think.

I'm sharing an entire drive. I can get onto the drive and see the 1 folder i've created on it, but that's all i can do, i can't create other folders nor enter the already ekscisting one. I don't know if this is related to the login part.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server has share-level permissions and file-level permissions.
It sounds like you have managed to change the share-level permissions, but not the file-level permissions.

If you want to give write access to non-authenticated users, you have to add file-level permissions to "Everyone" in the "Security" tab on the folder / drive. (Use "Edit" or "Advanced").

[image: Drive or folder properties]

I would not recommend this approach. Anyone connecting to your network would have write access. I would suggest connecting to the shared folder / drive with username and password from the client, and saving the credentials. (Use "Map network drive" and check for "Connect using different credentials", and then check the "Remember my credentials" when adding the username / password).

[image: Map network drive]
[image: Password]

Comment: Oh yeah, that helped. Thanks.


I understand why you wouldn't recommend it, for let's say businesses or the like. 
But this server is located on my home network, it's only me who is going to connect to it. And potential guest coming around with their laptops or phones won't connect to it even by accident as you have to connect to the drive as you mentioned "\\server\share"
And none of my guests will know that they can do that.


So for home use this is just fine.

Comment: I would still not do it. Anyone connecting with an infected laptop would cause a lot of trouble.

Comment: Ease of use wins over security.

Comment: Have an addon question @Ost99 This worked perfectly on my win8.1 desktop. But on my win10 laptop it is still being asked for credentials. What gives?

Comment: Are any of them part of a domain? Windows 8 would first try with the current logged in user, not sure if Windows 10 does that. If you have permissions set to Everyone, anything should be accepted - but I'm unsure if Windows 10 tries to send something before prompting for credentials. You could try to go to the control panel and add credentials for the server. (Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager)

Comment: They aren't. I'll have a look at credential manager and see if that does anything.